# Reflection through a hyperplane, orthogonality propoerty

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, reflection

While I was studying for my exam, I found Stanford's EE263 course's old homework questions and this particular one attracted my attention, however couldn't solve it. If you can help me, I will really appreciate it!

> Find the matrix $Q \in R^{n*n} $ such that the reflection of $x$
>   through the hyperplane $\left\{  z | a^Tz = 0\right \}$ is given by
>   $Qx$. Verify that matrix $Q$ is orthogonal. (To reflect $x$ through
>   the hyperplane means the following: find the point $z$ on the
>   hyperplane closest to $x$. Starting from x, go in the direction $z-x$
>   through the hyperplane to a point on the opposite side, which has the
>   same distance to $z$ as $x$ does. )

Comment: Hint: reflection through a hyperplane negates the component of the vector that’s orthogonal to it.

Comment: Check out the second part of the first question: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs205/homework/hw2_solutions.pdf